# File_exists always false in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have written small CMS in Laravel 4 and I was working on it using wamp. Application was in `www` folder and everything was working fine.
When I have finished with development, I moved an application to my live server and I have put application in `root` folder of my hosting (folder above `public_html`).
In some functions I'm checking if some files exist, and while I was on wamp, everything worked, but now `file_exists()` always returns `false`. 
Folder permissions of the folder where files are stored are set to 755, and files are with same permissions.

I have already tried `clearstatcache()` and Safe mode cannot be an issue since it was removed in PHP 5.4. Any other ideas?

```
if(file_exists('public_html/repo/images/testimage.jpg')){
    //do something
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
```

I have checked several times, and file does exists if I try to access it via url

Comment: Turn off safe mode using `safe_mode_include_dir`? Also, `ls -l /home/user/public_html/root/` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I'd bet that the path to the files is different, and you're either using a leading `/` when you shouldn't be, or you've omitted it when you shouldn't. Can you post some code please?

Comment: `safe_mode_include_dir` is already at `no value`. I thought it was php 5.4 and it is 5.3.26. Safe mode is off.
Also I have added sample code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first you said you were in WAMP, it could be that folders were having uppercases. Remember, windows is not case-sensitive for folder while linux is.

Second, where's laravel's `index.php` file? (It's generaly in `public` folder), `file_exists()` is relative to it, so if your installation is: `public_html/public/index.php` and `repo/images` is on `public` folder you should check for: `file_exists('repo/images...');`

Laravel is designed to keep its files outside of public access, so I suggest you put laravel's files and folders in the root `/` while moving everything in `public` folder to `public_html`. This way, you could check file existence relatively to `public_html` folder.

```
file_exists('repo/images...');
file_exists('../app/views/hello.blade.php');
...
```

Comment: Everything is in the root and basically my `public` folder is `public_html`

Comment: so don't include 'public_html' in the path